# Rails 4 multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

The following ActiveRecord query results in the error "The multi-part identifer question_answer_response.response_group could not be bound."

This just started happening after upgrading from Rails 3.2.x to Rails 4.0.x

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.fetch_dependencies(section_id)
    self.select('questions.*,question_answer_response.response as response,question_answer_response.response_group as response_group').
         includes({:dependency_conditions => :dependency}).
         where("dependencies.survey_section_id = #{section_id} and questions.survey_section_id != dependencies.survey_section_id")
  end

end
```

Comment: Who is "self"? Also, could you paste the resulting query from log or console?

Comment: @RubyRacer, I've updated the code snippet to clear that up. Here self is my Question model which is inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: I think you need to `joins(:question_answer_response)`. Also please provide the code where you called this method.

Comment: As waqar mirza sais, I'm quite certain that in the resulting sql syntax you will see that 'from question_answer_response' is not present, whilst it should. Thus, the sql syntax error.

Comment: Adding the join in fixes the issue; I'm more surprised by the fact that it was working in Rails 3.  Is there some type of change where `select` would do an implicit join previously?

Comment: Active Record and Rails 4 fix some fuzzy sql composition issues. Not "bugs" per say, but issues. The latter functionality is more correct than the former.